# SHFileOperation makes directory "undeletable"

Tags: qt, winapi, win32-process, shfileoperation

Okay, so I have an application that creates a sub-directory inside the %TEMP% directory to keep some intermediate files, while the application is still running. And, when the application is about to exit, I will call a clean-up function in order to *recursively* delete my sub-directory from %TEMP% again, so we don't leave any "garbage" files behind. So far, this works fine in 99.9% of all cases. But in some *very rare* cases, the clean-up function failed to delete my sub-directory! Testing showed that, when the clean-up succeeds, it always does so in the *first* attempt. And, when it failed, in the first attempt, retrying didn't help. I can retry 9999 times and it would fail 9999 times again. Bummer!

So, obviously, "my" directory was *blocked* for some reason. Now, I would have understood this, if there still had been some file (or sub-directory) within "my" directory. But it was *completely empty*! **No** files (not even hidden ones!) and **no** sub-directories. Just an empty directory. Still it could *not* be deleted. To make things even more obscure, it only failed to be deleted from my own process. It *could* be deleted from Windows Explorer or Total Commander perfectly fine - even while my process was still running.

Now, after many hours of testing, I figured out that **SHFileOperation()** is to blame. In some cases, I used **SHFileOperation()** to *copy* a file *to* "my" directory. And, whenever I did that, this made that directory "undeletable" for an undisclosed reason! To make it clear again: The *file* that I copied to "my" directory via **SHFileOperation()** could be deleted perfectly fine. It's the directory that could **no** longer be deleted - from within "my" process only. Using **CopyFile()** instead of **SHFileOperation()** immediately resolved the issue. Still I would like to understand what's going on with the **SHFileOperation()** function...

If anybody has an idea, I would be happy to know...

Regards!

---

**~ UPDATE #1 ~**

Okay, so I have put together an example, as requested:

```
#define COPY_METHOD 0

static wchar_t *pathToBuffer(const QString &path)
{
    const QString nativePath = QDir::toNativeSeparators(path);
    wchar_t *buffer = new wchar_t[nativePath.length() + 2];
    wcscpy_s(buffer, path.length() + 2, (const wchar_t*) nativePath.utf16());
    buffer[nativePath.length()] = buffer[nativePath.length() + 1] = L'\0';
    return buffer;
}

bool some_function(const QString &sourceFile, const QString &outputFile, volatile bool *abortFlag)
{
    emit messageLogged(QString("Copy file \"%1\" to \"%2\"").arg(sourceFile, outputFile));

/*---------------------------*/
#if(COPY_METHOD == 0)
/*---------------------------*/

    QScopedArrayPointer<wchar_t> srcBuffer(pathToBuffer(sourceFile));
    QScopedArrayPointer<wchar_t> outBuffer(pathToBuffer(outputFile));

    SHFILEOPSTRUCTW fileOperation;
    memset(&fileOperation, 0, sizeof(SHFILEOPSTRUCTW));

    fileOperation.wFunc  = FO_COPY;
    fileOperation.fFlags = FOF_SILENT | FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR | FOF_NOERRORUI | FOF_FILESONLY;
    fileOperation.pFrom  = srcBuffer.data();
    fileOperation.pTo    = outBuffer.data();

    emit statusUpdated(0);
    int result = SHFileOperationW(&fileOperation);
    emit statusUpdated(100);

    return (result == 0 && fileOperation.fAnyOperationsAborted == false);

/*---------------------------*/
#elif(COPY_METHOD == 1)
/*---------------------------*/

    emit statusUpdated(0);
    const BOOL success = CopyFile((const wchar_t*) QDir::toNativeSeparators(sourceFile).utf16(), (const wchar_t*) QDir::toNativeSeparators(outputFile).utf16(), FALSE);
    emit statusUpdated(100);

    return (success != FALSE);

/*---------------------------*/
#elif(COPY_METHOD == 2)
/*---------------------------*/

    if(QFile::exists(outputFile))
    {
        QFile::remove(outputFile);
    }

    emit statusUpdated(0);
    QFile src(sourceFile);
    const bool success = src.copy(outputFile);
    emit statusUpdated(100);

    if(!success)
    {
        emit messageLogged(QString("Failed to copy file: %1").arg(src.errorString()));
    }

    return success;

/*---------------------------*/
#else
/*---------------------------*/

#error Invalid copy method specified!

/*---------------------------*/
#endif //COPY_METHOD
/*---------------------------*/
}
```

Method **#0** is what I was doing originally. And, as soon as I do that, the directory where the file has been copied to (not the file itself!) becomes "undeletable" later on. This is reproducible. And, as soon as I use either method **#1** or method **#2** (and **no** other changes are made at all) the problem is resolved...

In the first post I said that it only happens rarely. Yes, because (normally) the function "some_function" is only called rarely. But when this function gets called (or when I *force* it to be called), then the problem happens **always** - at least as long as I still use copy method **#0**.

Finally, when the directory can **not** be deleted, the error returned by the system is a very unspecific "access denied" (Win32 Error 0x5), so this doesn't help much. If it does occurs, then the problem occurs with the **RemoveDirectoy()** function as well as the **QDir::rmdir()** method. The directory is **empty**.

---

**~ UPDATE #2 ~**

Okay, here is a full example, adapted from code provided by Harry Johnston:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    if(!CreateDirectoryW(L"C:\\Users\\MuldeR\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\umTpRwui9MpP", NULL))
    {
        printf("CreateDirectory Failed: Error %u\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    const wchar_t *const sourceFile = L"C:\\Windows\\Media\\ding.wav\0";
    const wchar_t *const outputFile = L"C:\\Users\\MuldeR\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\umTpRwui9MpP\\test.wav\0";

    SHFILEOPSTRUCTW fileOperation;
    memset(&fileOperation, 0, sizeof(SHFILEOPSTRUCTW));

    fileOperation.wFunc = FO_COPY;
    fileOperation.fFlags = FOF_SILENT | FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR | FOF_NOERRORUI | FOF_FILESONLY;
    fileOperation.pFrom = sourceFile;
    fileOperation.pTo = outputFile;

    int result = SHFileOperationW(&fileOperation);
    if (result != 0)
    {
        printf("SHFileOperation Failed: Error%u\n", result);
        return 1;
    }

    if(!DeleteFileW(outputFile))
    {
        printf("DeleteFile Failed: Error %u\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    if (!RemoveDirectoryW(L"C:\\Users\\MuldeR\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\umTpRwui9MpP"))
    {
        printf("RemoveDirectory Failed: Error %u\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("OK\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**Result is:** *RemoveDirectory Failed: Error 5*

Comment: Hmm, that's unlikely.  Somebody has a lock on the directory, by far the most common reason is that the directory is your program's default working directory.  Or another process', like Explorer while you are looking at the directory.  You should not be doing this anyway, there is no cleanup when your program bombs.  Clean up when you start, not when you terminate.  And don't try too hard, the directory disappears when the last handle on it is closed.

Comment: Well, as long as I don't use **SHFileOperation()** to copy something into "my" directory, I can delete it perfectly fine - even when it's currently open in Explorer. The Explorer *automatically* goes one level up when I delete the directory, which was currently showing in Explorer, from my process. That's not the problem I think. But also tried with all Explorer windows closed. Didn't make a difference. Even searched for an open handle to the directory with ProcessExplorer, but found nothing suspicious. (BTW: cleanup at the beginning isn't possible, it would be a NOP. Have to do it at the end)

Comment: Are you saying that if you use `SHFileOperation` to do the copy, the folder will **always** be undeletable?

Comment: Yes, it was reproducible. Doing the step that involved **SHFileOperation()** *reproducible* caused the problem - folder can no longer be deleted. If I skipped that step, all was fine. And, replacing **SHFileOperation()** with **CopyFile()** fixed it *instantly* too. So probably a **SHFileOperation()** issue.

Comment: It does sound like it. Can you create a self-contained example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Yes, I will try to create a minimal example.

Comment: For debugging try printing the results of `GetCurrentDirectory` before and after the call to `SHFileOperation`.

Comment: I have tried that before, because I am aware that the process' "current" directory cannot be deleted. But my test shows that the "current" directory is the directory where my executable is located - a *different* one from that which I try to delete. And **SHFileOperation()** doesn't change the current directory. Current directory is still the same as before, after **SHFileOperation()** returns.

Comment: Please make a minimal example. A complete program. And with no Qt.

Comment: @MuldeR: I've put together a simple test program, see http://pastebin.com/gEqterZs and I can't reproduce the problem.  Does the problem occur for you using my code?

Comment: @Harry Johnston: Thanks for your efforts! I have adapted your example code a bit, please see above. Result is: Remove directory failed with the error #5 ("Access is denied").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you're copying has a localized shell filename, as can be seen by looking in the `desktop.ini` file in the source folder:

```
c:\windows\media\desktop.ini
```

The shell copy operation copies this localized name, which means it:

- creates a `desktop.ini` file in the target folder
- marks the target folder read-only

To remove the directory, you need to delete `desktop.ini` and reset the read-only flag.

You *could* do this manually:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define target L"C:\\Users\\MuldeR\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\umTpRwui9MpP"

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    if(!CreateDirectoryW(target, NULL))
    {
        printf("CreateDirectory Failed: Error %u\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    const wchar_t *const sourceFile = L"C:\\Windows\\Media\\ding.wav\0";
    const wchar_t *const outputFile = target L"\\test.wav\0";

    SHFILEOPSTRUCTW fileOperation;
    memset(&fileOperation, 0, sizeof(SHFILEOPSTRUCTW));

    fileOperation.wFunc = FO_COPY;
    fileOperation.fFlags = FOF_SILENT | FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR | FOF_NOERRORUI | FOF_FILESONLY;
    fileOperation.pFrom = sourceFile;
    fileOperation.pTo = outputFile;

    int result = SHFileOperationW(&fileOperation);
    if (result != 0)
    {
        printf("SHFileOperation Failed: Error%u\n", result);
        return 1;
    }

    if(!DeleteFileW(outputFile))
    {
        printf("DeleteFile(outputFile) Failed: Error %u\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    if (!DeleteFileW(target L"\\desktop.ini"))
    {
        printf("DeleteFile(desktop.ini) Failed: Error %u\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    if (!SetFileAttributes(target, 0))
    {
        printf("SetFileAttributes Failed: Error %u\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    if (!RemoveDirectoryW(target))
    {
        printf("RemoveDirectory Failed: Error %u\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("OK\n");
    return 0;
}
```

But since you created the target directory with the shell, it would be more consistent to delete it the same way, and of course that takes care of the details for you:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define target L"C:\\Users\\MuldeR\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\umTpRwui9MpP"

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    if(!CreateDirectoryW(target, NULL))
    {
        printf("CreateDirectory Failed: Error %u\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    const wchar_t *const sourceFile = L"C:\\Windows\\Media\\ding.wav\0";
    const wchar_t *const outputFile = target L"\\test.wav\0";

    SHFILEOPSTRUCTW fileOperation;
    memset(&fileOperation, 0, sizeof(SHFILEOPSTRUCTW));

    fileOperation.wFunc = FO_COPY;
    fileOperation.fFlags = FOF_SILENT | FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR | FOF_NOERRORUI | FOF_FILESONLY;
    fileOperation.pFrom = sourceFile;
    fileOperation.pTo = outputFile;

    int result = SHFileOperationW(&fileOperation);
    if (result != 0)
    {
        printf("SHFileOperation Failed: Error%u\n", result);
        return 1;
    }

    memset(&fileOperation, 0, sizeof(SHFILEOPSTRUCTW));

    fileOperation.wFunc = FO_DELETE;
    fileOperation.fFlags = FOF_SILENT | FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | FOF_NOERRORUI;
    fileOperation.pFrom = target L"\0";

    result = SHFileOperationW(&fileOperation);
    if (result != 0)
    {
        printf("SHFileOperation Failed: Error%u\n", result);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("OK\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The "Desktop.ini" I noticed too. But that isn't the problem, because my original code recursively deleted all files and sub-directories. However, I didn't know that **directories** can be "read only" on Windows! In the Windows Explorer this isn't exposed at all - you can only make the files in a folder "read only", **not** the folder itself. Also, Explorer seems to happily delete the "read only" directory, without complaining or at least showing a warning! I will update my clean-up code to clear directory "read only" flags. BTW: I do not *create* the directory with the Shell.

Comment: You probably don't need `FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR` then, but I don't suppose it does any harm. :-)